# Inject AsyncCollector into a service

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

The AsyncCollector is a very nice way of simplifying sending messages

However this involves having logic in an azure function whereas I prefer to have my logic in services

How can I inject an AsyncCollector into a service?

Paul